# How to auto rerun of failed action in oozie?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

How can I re-run any action which was failed in the workflow automatically?

I know the way to rerun manually from command line or thorough hue.

```
$oozie job -rerun ...
```

Is there any parameter we can set or provide in workflow to retry automatically when action fails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the time, when an action fails in the Oozie workflow, you need to debug and fix the error and rerun the workflow. But there are times, when you want Oozie to retry the action after an interval, for fixed number of times before failing the workflow. You can specify the `retry-max` and `retry-interval` in the action definition.

Examples of User-Retry in a workflow action is :

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="wf-name">
<action name="a" retry-max="2" retry-interval="1">
.... 
</action>
```

You can find the more information about the [User-Retry for Workflow Actions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a18_User-Retry_for_Workflow_Actions_since_Oozie_3.1) in the link.